# How to check if adapter device is present in device tree? In /proc/device-tree

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree

How to check if the device is present in device tree using /proc/device-tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/proc/device-tree will give you info only about the configured information and not about the running status of the device. If the device driver is not creating/using a folder in /proc directory then I think you should better look under /sys/class to see if the device is available and also the current status.